# offset().top gives error in IE7: offset().top is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7, scrollto, scrolltop

I use the following piece of code to make a div's position fixed when scrolled down (so it will stay in the window). It works perfectly fine, but in IE7 I get the error: `offset().top is null or not an object.`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var msie6 = $.browser == 'msie' && $.browser.version < 7;

    if (!msie6) {
    var top = $('#comment').offset().top - parseFloat($('#comment').css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
        // what the y position of the scroll is
        var y = $(this).scrollTop();

        // whether that's below the form
        if (y >= top) {
            // if so, ad the fixed class
            $('#comment').addClass('fixed');
        } else {
            // otherwise remove it
            $('#comment').removeClass('fixed');
        }
     });
   }
});
```

Googling I found this (see bottom post by Earl Jenkins) http://api.jquery.com/offset/
In which he solves this particular error. But, jQuery & javascript beginner as I am, I don't know how to implement this fix, because in his post he uses a fixed value (100), and in the piece of code above it doesn't.

I tried to fix by doing this:

```
var fix = $('#comment').offset();
var top = fix.top - parseFloat($('#comment').css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
```

But it doesn't do the trick. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Earl Jenkin's solution appears to be about setting the value, not retrieving it.

Comment: Hmm then that's probably not what i'm looking for. Retrieving a value seemingly gives about the same error.

Comment: The problem is that the function inside offset() must return an anonymous object that evaluates to a "position", i.e.:

$("p:last").offset(function(index, coords) {
alert(index);
alert(coords.left);
return {left: 999, top:999}; //<-- you need to return this.
});

Comment: Is the above something i could use (few posts above)? How would I implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem you were running into was that you were accessing the `top` property of the `window` object when your `#comment` DIV wasn't present.

This problem isn't well documented, but I've run into it before.  I found a vague explanation of the cause at [Dottoro.com's reference to the window object](http://help.dottoro.com/ljrwrqew.php).

> The `window` object is accessible from anywhere in the JavaScript code, so do not use variables with the same names as the members of the `window` object (although if you declare a variable with the same name as any member of the `window` object, the member of the `window` object stays accessible through the `window` object).

The gist of it is that if you had changed your variable name from top to something else, the problem would've gone away.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem.

This javascript was loaded in the head of every page, but on only one page the div '#comment' exists. Somehow in modern browser this doesn't give an error, but IE7 has trouble handling it. Now I let this piece of code only be executed on that particular page where #comment existed and the error is gone!